# Hardened Runtime permission for USB HID? "TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen"

Tags: macos, usb, hid, macos-catalina

I have enabled Hardened Runtime for my program on MacOS Catalina. My program communicates with certain USB HID devices. (They use USB HID so they will be driverless on all platforms.) I notice in the Console the error "TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen", and my program is no longer seeing the device. What entitlements do I need to set to get things running again?

Comment: Check the runtime permissions (ensure your app is listed in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Security > Input Monitoring)